# How to add and update config varaibles in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, variables, config, laravel-5.3

I have a config variable file which I'm using it in my controllers instead of mysql for faster performance.

But my problem is that I can only read from this config file and I can not add or update any value from it.

any suggestion how to update or add new values to this variable file :

my variable file which is stored in `/config/Banners_size.php`:

```
return [
    "normal_x970h90" => [
        'status' => 'enable',
        'value' => '500'
    ],

    "normal_x234h60" => [
        'status' => 'enable',
        'value' => '500'
    ],
]
```

my php code to add new array to it which is not working :

```
    $banners = Config('Banners_size');
    $banner = array(
        $request->input('size') => [
            'status' => $request->input('status'),
             'value' => $request->input('cost')
        ]
    );

   $bannerinfo = array_merge($banners, $banner);

   Config('Banners_size' , $bannerinfo);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration files are read only files, you cannot add parameters to it programmatically.

```
$banners = config('Banners_size');

config('Banners_size' , $bannerinfo);
```

The above two lines, will act the same, and will both return the value of `Banner_size`.

Comment: so there is no way to write to this files ?

Comment: You can only do that by writing the actual values to the file. In other words append the array with the new values, not during run-time.

Answer (score 9):

To set configuration values at runtime, pass an array to the config helper:

```
config(['app.timezone' => 'America/Chicago']);
```

*Note - It will not persist the data for the next request*

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values)

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could...

```
//edit config for current runtime
config(['FILE.KEY' => 'NEW_VALUE']);
// open config file for writing
$fp = fopen(base_path() .'/config/FILE.php' , 'w');
// write updated runtime config to file
fwrite($fp, '<?php return ' . var_export(config('FILE'), true) . ';');
// close the file
fclose($fp);
// clear config cache
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```

Comment: This is a brilliant use case for my scenario.

Comment: this removes all comments in config, makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

class Uid
{

   /*
    * $name => Config Name
    * $keys => [Data Type Array] The key whose value you want to change; Example : ['theme.color','theme.font']
    * $values => [Data Type Array] The new value, you can add an array Example : ['#fff','Roboto']
    * $implodeCharacter => spacers between keys 
    */

    public static function putConfig($name,$keys,$values,$implodeCharacter = '.' )
    {
        $path = base_path('config/'.$name.'.php');
        $config = config($name);

        $data = self::findAndReplace($keys, $config,$values,$implodeCharacter);

        file_put_contents($path,'<?php
        return '.var_export($data,true).';');

        Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    }

    public static function findAndReplace($keys, $config,$values,$implodeCharacter) {
       for($i=0;$i < count($keys);$i++) {
        $parts = explode($implodeCharacter, $keys[$i]);
        if(count($parts) == 1):
            $config[$parts[0]] = $values[$i];
        elseif(count($parts) == 2):
            $config[$parts[0]][$parts[1]] = $values[$i];
        elseif(count($parts) == 3):
            $config[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]] = $values[$i];
        elseif(count($parts) == 4):
            $config[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]][$parts[3]] = $values[$i];
        elseif(count($parts) == 5):
            $config[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]][$parts[3]][$parts[4]] = $values[$i];
        elseif(count($parts) == 6):
            $config[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]][$parts[3]][$parts[4]][$parts[5]] = $values[$i];
        elseif(count($parts) == 7):
            $config[$parts[0]][$parts[1]][$parts[2]][$parts[3]][$parts[4]][$parts[5]][$parts[6]] = $values[$i];
        endif;
    }

    return $config;
    }

}
```